# grunt-contrib-clean task doesn't delete files with network src path

Tags: gruntjs

I faced a trouble attempting to clean distributive directory on remote file server.
I have a folder and access it via double slash notation like

```
//foldername/projectname/subfolder/
```

I've configured my Gruntfile.js for grunt-contrib-clean task like this:

```
clean: {
    files: [
        {
            src: ['//foldername/projectname/subfolder/']
        }
    ]
}
```

In my tasks list I also have a grunt-contrib-copy task which launches after grunt-contrib-clean to load distributive and this task **uses the same src path to folder on network**.

So when i launch the grunt - "clean" task actually doesn't clean the subfolder but the "copy" succesfully copies files.
When I try to launch grunt with --verbose command i have a next log:

```
Running "clean" (clean) task
Verifying property clean exists in config...OK
Files: [no src]
Options: force=false, no-write=false
Options: force=false, no-write=false
```

So it seems that task can't find the files but the reason is undefined.
Access to server is authorized and i'm enter credentials via default Windows prompt. And I have credentials for changing/deleting folder.

Can anybody help me and answer why the clean task doesn't find my directory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It does. Here is an example:

```
dev: {
          options: {
            'force': true
          },
          expand: true,
          cwd: '//someserver/someshare/somepath',
          src: '{,*/}*'
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use force=true to go clean the subfolder:

```
force

Type: Boolean
Default: false

This overrides this task from blocking deletion of folders outside current working dir (CWD). Use with caution.
```

and no-write=true to get verbose output.

Also, check the version to see if the Windows bug has been fixed:

```
2013-07-15   v0.5.0   Use rimraf directly, version 2.2.1 to fix issue on Windows. Add no-write option to mimic grunt.file.delete behavior.
```

**References**

- [npmjs: grunt-contrib-clean](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-clean)
- [grunt-contrib-clean: Failing on Windows 8](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean/issues/25)